# General change of random variable with unequal dimensions

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus

- $\vec{X} = (X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{m})$ is a vector of $m$ random variables
- The probability distribution of $\vec{X}$ is $\rho_{X}(\vec{x})$
- $\vec{Y} = f(\vec{X}) = (Y_{1}, Y_{2}, \ldots, X_{n})$ is a vector of $n$ random variables
- The probability distribution of $\vec{Y}$ is $\rho_{Y}(\vec{y})$
- $n \gt m$
- $\vec{Z} = (Y_{1}, Y_{2}, \ldots Y_{m})$ is a vector formed by a subset of the random variables in $\vec{Y}$
- $g(\vec{Z}) = \vec{Y}$
- $h(\vec{X}) = \vec{Z}$
- $f$, $g$, $h$ are all invertible functions.

---

By change of variable formula in calculus, we have:

$\rho_{Z}(\vec{z})d\vec{z} = \rho_{X}(h^{-1}(\vec{z})) d\vec{x}$

$\rho_{Z}(\vec{z}) = \rho_{X}(h^{-1}(\vec{z})) \lvert \det(J) \rvert$

where the Jacobian $J$ is:

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_{1}(\vec{z})}{\partial z_{1}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial x_{1}(\vec{z})}{\partial z_{m}} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial x_{m}(\vec{z})}{\partial z_{1}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial x_{m}(\vec{z})}{\partial z_{m}} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Is the following true in general?

$\rho_{Y}(\vec{y}) = \rho_{Z}(g^{-1}(Y))$

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't work. At least need an extra term for $g$.